# Array mapping is always not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've been fiddling with arrays and mapping them using the `Array.prototype.map()` fucntion and honestly i've been struggleing ALOT so i hope somebody can share some light on this.

So my goal is simple to map some headings and rows in a table in my custom component, but when i get to make the mapping its always says `"variable.map() is not a function"` event tho im specifying its an array and it has values im passing on from my page.
I have already tested if its was because it was empty but it doesnt seem that way.

My page is simply this for now.

```
import AppLayout from '../../../components/AppLayout';
import Table from '../../../components/modules/Table';

export default function Products() {
  return (
    <AppLayout>
      <section className="content">
        <h3 className="text-3xl font-bold">Products</h3>
        <Table
          headings={[
            '',
            'Product',
            'Status',
            'Type',
          ]}
        />
      </section>
    </AppLayout>
  );
}
```

As for my table its:

```
export default function Table(headings = [], rows = {}) {
  const top = headings.map((value) => (
    <th
      key={value}
      scope="col"
      className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
    >
      {value}
    </th>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div className="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
        <div className="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
            <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
              <thead className="bg-gray-50">
                {top}
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {rows}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've had other issues with mapping arrays but this is the most one i always fail one idk why SO ANNOYING.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your mapping and it works fine. I think the problem is with your data extraction. You should modify your code as follow:

```
export default function Table({headings = [], rows = {}}) {
```

or

```
export default function Table(props) {
  {headings, rows} = props;
```

Comment: Thanks i that was something i didn know haha, its just sometimes the smallest problems thats seems the most annoying, but thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Component props will always be an *object*, so you need to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties from that object:

```
Table({ headings = [], rows = [] })
```

I've changed rows to an array too because, although you don't pass any row property into that component at the moment, I'm pretty sure that it will also be an array that will also need to be `map`ped over.

Comment: Thanks thats true, but in my case i need the object but it might be better to go with arrays on that to for future development.

Comment: Ideally you just want to hand `data` to the `Table` component, and then use it's internal functions to separate out the headings and rows.